# Some custom themes showing twice in theme list

Tags: theming

I have a site using the Domain access module to serve content to 18 different sites, all which have their own domain. I have five different custom themes installed in addition to the stock themes.

For some reason, in my theme list three of my custom themes are showing up twice; each have two screenshots. I have the correct ones enabled and assigned to the proper domains and it's all working fine, I just want to delete those double entries.

The sites/all/themes folder is clean with only one folder per theme and I've cleared caches, pushed live etc hundreds of times and it's not causing any issues, but I'd like to clean it up.

Any ideas? Drupal 6.28.

Comment: If theme folder is uploaded by mistake to the inside of another folder, it will be detected by Drupal, too. Looks like someone uploaded themes to the wrong place.

Comment: Is there a way in phpMyAdmin to delete those? I've also seen something about not disabling a theme when adding to the folder before refreshing the theme list as well. Strange

Comment: Yes, there is, kinda. You can delete them from `system` table, but if they are on disk, they will reappear. Are you sure they are not uploaded twice? Have you searched the template directories for all info files to test it?

Comment: Ok, I found out what happened. I had copies of "STARTERKIT.info" still in the themes folder. Newbie miss. Thanks!